# PDO before delete rowCount() returns null, when query key exists

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
public function deleteComment( $id, $check_author = true ) {
        $q = $this -> database -> prepare( "SELECT `id`, `aid` FROM `addon_comments` WHERE `id` = :id" );
        $q -> execute( array( 'id' => $id ) );

        if( !$q -> rowCount( ) )
            return -1;

        $r      = $q -> fetch( );
        $uid    = $this -> registry -> getClass( 'Users' ) -> isLogged( );

        if( $check_author && $r[ 'aid' ] != $uid )
            return -2;


        $s = $this -> database -> prepare( "DELETE FROM `addon_comments` WHERE `id` = :id OR `parent` = :id" );
        $s -> execute( array( 'id' => $id ) );

        return 1;           
    }
```

Function returns to me -1, but row are deleted by query.. When i comment a delete query, everything are ok (funcion returns 1)..
What i've done wrong?

Comment: Those whitespaces hurt my eyes `$object -> execute ( "asd", array ( ) )` :(

Comment: I don't see any way that it can return `-1` and also delete rows. When the `return` statement is executed, the function stops.

Comment: I just saw the name, I apologise :)

Comment: Doesn't the PDO documentation say that `rowCount()` is not reliable after a `SELECT`? If you want to know if it returned any rows, call `$q->fetch()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code below will return true if a row is successfully selected:

```
if( $q -> rowCount( ) )
    return -1;
```

I suggest if you want to check a negative result and for it to return `-1`, use:

```
if($q->rowCount() < 1)
    return -1;
```

Comment: That's not that.. It's something like function rowCount() returns number of rows after delete query..

Comment: No, it is not just for `DELETE` queries.  It works for UPDATE, INSERT and SELECT if you're using MYSQL.  [This is mentioned in the first box in the documentation for rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).  If that was the case, why are you using it immediately after an insert?

Comment: You don't understand me.. My function behaves as if returns number of rows in database, after execute delete query..